# Connect to Oracle database in VB

Tags: vb.net, oracle, visual-studio-2010

I have some deprecated code in visual basic when connecting to an oracle database. I am using a OracleDataAdapter but it says that this has been deprecated. Does anyone know what the new supported code is to connect to a database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle provides a Data Provider for .NET

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

This blog post may be of help as well.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/15/system-data-oracleclient-update.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at the `OleDbConnection`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.aspx