# How to pass Datatable from vb to Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: vb.net, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, datatable

I need to pass several rows of data  to an oracle stored procedure and perform multiple operations per row in the procedure.
I cant seem to find a proper solution for sending a datatable.

I had created custom table type in oracle and used a parameter of this type as input param in procedure.
At vb end i directly added a datatable as parameter.
This however is giving error- cannot convert datatable to object.

custom types

```
create or replace   TYPE FORECAST_TYP AS OBJECT 
(
CUSTOMER VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
SALESLEVEL VARCHAR2(3 BYTE), 
SERV_LOC VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
PROC_LOC VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
PROCESSED VARCHAR2(15 BYTE), 
PRODLINE VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
ITEMGROUP VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
QTY NUMBER,
MNTH1 DATE, 
CUSTOMER_DESC VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
SERV_LOC_DESC VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
PROC_LOC_DESC VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
ITEMGROUP_DESC VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
PI_DESC VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
VERTICAL VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
STEEL_TYPE VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
PI VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)
)   NOT FINAL;`

create or replace TYPE FORECAST_TAB_TYP AS TABLE OF FORECAST_TYP;
```

the procedure declaration is like this:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE      SCDMB000 (
  ps_fore_table forecast_tab_typ,
  ps_err_code   OUT   VARCHAR2,
  ps_err_var    OUT   VARCHAR2
)
```

Note: I donot have problem connecting to Oracle DB
I m using the default data provider that comes with visual studio 2013. System.data.oracleclient namespace and dot net 3.5.

Comment: What data access library are you using the oracle odp.net data provider?

Comment: don't know about .net but for java you can create database object as rowtype collection in database; and through jdbc connection in java you can create variable of that oracle datatype we have create in database, just fill that variable pass to procedure; input parameter for procedure will also be same data_type we have created/

Comment: What you really need to do is to read this http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28844/building_odp.htm and do what it says

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connect to Oracle database in VB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985069/connect-to-oracle-database-in-vb)

Comment: @T.S. I donot have problem connecting to oracle db and the article [link](docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28844/building_odp.htm)  doesnot include sending multiple rows to a STORED PROCEDURE where multiple operations are to be performed for each row

Comment: You should use `ODP.NET` if you want to do any complex operations with Oracle. Microsoft provides `System.data.oracleclient` but recommends *vendor-proveded sata access components*. You may able to pass structures into SP from code but it will probably be custom type. If you want to pass single-bound arrays, it is easy with ODP.NET. You can also pass your table as XML. Directly passing table to SP, I don't think is possible